# Set test case source using TextFixtureAttribute

Tags: c#, nunit, nunit-3.0

I created the following test fixture template to test `Equals` method of a custom class.

```
class TestTemplate<X, Y>
{
    public virtual void Reflexivity(X x)
    {
        bool isEqual = x.Equals(x);
        Assert.IsTrue(isEqual);
    }

    public virtual void Symmetry(X x, Y y)
    {
        bool xy = x.Equals(y);
        bool yx = y.Equals(x);
        Assert.AreEqual(xy, yx);
    }

    public virtual void Transitivity(X x, Y y, Y z)
    {
        bool xy = x.Equals(y);
        bool yz = y.Equals(z);
        bool xz = x.Equals(z);
        Assert.IsTrue(!(xy && yz) || xz);
    }

    public virtual void NullTest(X x)
    {
        bool isEqual = x.Equals(null);
        Assert.IsFalse(isEqual);
    }

    public virtual void EqualTest(X x, Y equivalent)
    {
        bool isEqual = x.Equals(equivalent);
        Assert.IsTrue(isEqual);
    }

    public virtual void InqualTest(X x, Y nonequivalent)
    {
        bool isEqual = x.Equals(nonequivalent);
        Assert.IsFalse(isEqual);
    }
}
```

Now I look for best way of the template usage.

#### 1 Derived test fixture

It is possible to inherit the template and provide a set of test cases using `TestCaseSourceAttribute`.

```
[TestFixture]
class ConcreteTest : TestTemplate<MyClass, MyClass>
{
    [TestCaseSource(typeof(ConcreteTestSource), "ReflexivitySet")]
    public override void Reflexivity(MyClass x) => base.Reflexivity(x);

    [TestCaseSource(typeof(ConcreteTestSource), "EqualitySet")]
    [TestCaseSource(typeof(ConcreteTestSource), "InequalitySet")]
    public override void Symmetry(MyClass x, MyClass y) => base.Symmetry(x, y);

    [TestCaseSource(typeof(ConcreteTestSource), "TransitivitySet")]
    public override void Transitivity(MyClass x, MyClass y, MyClass z) => base.Transitivity(x, y, z);

    [TestCaseSource(typeof(ConcreteTestSource), "ReflexivitySet")]
    public override void NullTest(MyClass x) => base.NullTest(x);

    [TestCaseSource(typeof(ConcreteTestSource), "EqualitySet")]
    public override void EqualTest(MyClass x, MyClass equivalent) => base.EqualTest(x, equivalent);

    [TestCaseSource(typeof(ConcreteTestSource), "InqualitySet")]
    public override void InqualTest(MyClass x, MyClass nonequivalent) => base.InqualTest(x, nonequivalent);
}
```

It works, but requires to define a separate test fixture class for each `Equals` implementation.

#### 2 Single fixture class usage

Another way is to apply `TestCaseSourceAttribute` to the base fixture methods directly.

```
[TestFixture]
class EqualityTests
{
    [TestCaseSource(typeof(Test1Source), "ReflexivitySet")]
    [TestCaseSource(typeof(Test2Source), "ReflexivitySet")]
    [TestCaseSource(typeof(Test3Source), "ReflexivitySet")]
    public virtual void Reflexivity(object x)
    {
        bool isEqual = x.Equals(x);
        Assert.IsTrue(isEqual);
    }

    // Symmetry, Transitivity, EqualTest, InqualTest and NullTest methods definition here
}
```

The resulting code is more concise and it works too. But I want to reduce the code even more. I belive it's possible to specify test case source just once.

#### 3 Trying to set test data source using fixture constructor

On the next step I tried to identify the test data source by passing source type to the fixture constructor through arguments of `TestFixtureAttribute`. The idea was to store the type using fixture field or property and then use it in `sourceType` argument of `TestCaseSourceAttribute`.

```
[TestFixture(typeof(Test1Source), TypeArgs = new Type[] { typeof(MyClass), typeof(MyClass) })]
[TestFixture(typeof(Test2Source), TypeArgs = new Type[] { typeof(ClassA), typeof(ClassA) })]
[TestFixture(typeof(Test3Source), TypeArgs = new Type[] { typeof(ClassA), typeof(ClassB) })]
class EqualityTests<X, Y>
{
    private Type _sourceType;

    public EqualityTests(Type sourceType)
    {
        _sourceType = sourceType;
    }

    [TestCaseSource(_sourceType, "SymmetrySet")]
    public virtual void Symmetry(X x, Y y)
    {
        bool xy = x.Equals(y);
        bool yx = y.Equals(x);
        Assert.AreEqual(xy, yx);
    }

    // Reflexivity, Transitivity, EqualTest, InqualTest and NullTest methods definition here
}
```

Of course, the code doesn't work, because `sourceType` attribute of `TestCaseSourceAttribute` requires constant or `typeof` expression.

#### 4 Trying to use parameterised test case source

Then I tried to use intermediate parameterised source, that selects concrete source and get test cases from one. It's some similar to previous solution but uses `methodParams` argument of `TestCaseSourceAttribute`.

```
[TestFixture(typeof(Test1Source), TypeArgs = new Type[] { typeof(MyClass), typeof(MyClass) })]
[TestFixture(typeof(Test2Source), TypeArgs = new Type[] { typeof(ClassA), typeof(ClassA) })]
[TestFixture(typeof(Test3Source), TypeArgs = new Type[] { typeof(ClassA), typeof(ClassB) })]
class EqualityTests<X, Y>
{
    private Type _sourceType;

    public EqualityTests(Type sourceType)
    {
        _sourceType = sourceType;
    }

    [TestCaseSource("GetSymmetryTestSet", new object[] { _sourceType })]
    public virtual void Symmetry(X x, Y y)
    {
        bool xy = x.Equals(y);
        bool yx = y.Equals(x);
        Assert.AreEqual(xy, yx);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<TestCaseData> GetSymmetryTestSet(Type sourceType)
    {
        // return Symmetry member value of the sourceType
    }

    // Reflexivity, Transitivity, EqualTest, InqualTest and NullTest methods definition here
}
```

But the solution also doesn't work for same reason: it's not possible to use non-static member of a fixture instance within `methodParams` argument of `TestCaseSourceAttribute`.

#### Question

So, I want to improve reusability and scalability of working solution (2). It should not require to define a new fixture for every `Equals` implementation or specify same test case source in several places. I hope it is possible, but I stuck to implement it. Please, let me know if you have any suggestion or expirience to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'd make all methods `public static` and use them explicitly.

```
class TestHelpers
{
    public static void AssertReflexivity<X>(X x)
    {
        bool isEqual = x.Equals(x);
        Assert.IsTrue("Add a good message here, otherwise test output may be hard to read");
    }

    public static AssertSymmetry<X,Y>(X x, Y y)
    {
        bool xy = x.Equals(y);
        bool yx = y.Equals(x);
        Assert.AreEqual(xy, yx, "Add a good message here, otherwise test output may be hard to read" );
    }
...
```

```
[Test]
public void Test1() {
   var x = new SomeType1()
   AssertReflexivity(x);
}

[Test]
public void Test2() {
   var x = new SomeType1();
   var y = new SomeType2();
   AssertReflexivity(x, y);
}
```

---

## Few points

### If this is about the same type

1. You could use one type in your class

```
class TestHelpers
{
    public static void AssertReflexivity<T>(T x)
    {
        bool isEqual = x.Equals(x);
        Assert.IsTrue("Add a good message here, otherwise test output may be hard to read");
    }

    public static AssertSymmetry<T>(T x, T y)
```

2. What if you compare two objects that have all their properties set to null? Are they reflexive?

### If this his about different types

- It hangs on how `Equals` is overridden/implemented - these tests could pass/fail in many different scenarios that don't have much to do with the relationships between types, but just the data setup.
- Should different types by reflexive?
- What if you compare two objects that have all their properties set to null? Are they reflexive?

Comment: Thank you for response. I like your idea. It's some similar as my first solution but your proposal is more flexible. Note, it also requires to define a test fixture class for each tested class and specify test case source for each test method. You ask good questions, but I think the questions about `Equals` implementation. I'm just trying to test [requirements for `Equals()` overriding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.equals?view=netframework-4.8#notes-for-inheritors).